# Accessing Sibling Elements in XML DOM using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

For my problem I am having a user enter a string to search for a provider, then the provider as well as some select plan information appears in the console. However, I cannot find out how to print out a select provider + the other information needed all in one.

For example:

Vodafone || 12 months || 120gb

Vodafone || 24 months || 200gb

I have made a start and do not mind too much about the sting input as I can figure that out later, but I cannot find how to firstly search for a select provider and then to print the information. Every provider and all the information is within a < plan > node (see XML below).

XML FILE

```
<plans>
    <internet>
        <plan>
            <technology>ADSL2+</technology>
            <length>12</length>
            <provider>Vodafone</provider>
            <price>60</price>
            <mincost>600</mincost>
            <data>120</data>
            <shaping>128</shaping>
            <homebundle>true</homebundle>
        </plan>
        <plan>
            <technology>ADSL2+</technology>
            <length>12</length>
            <provider>Telstra</provider>
            <price>80</price>
            <mincost>800</mincost>
            <data>200</data>
            <shaping>256</shaping>
            <homebundle>true</homebundle>
        </plan> 
        (etc.)
```

And the current Perl file

```
use XML::DOM;

my $dom_obj;
my $xml_file= shift;

my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;

die "Unable to parse XML document\n" unless $dom_obj = $parser->parsefile($xml_file);

my @nodes = $dom_obj->getElementsByTagName("plan"); #return list of objects of 'Plan'

foreach $elem (@nodes) #for each 'Plan' object
{
    foreach $child ($elem->getChildElements) #should return each element under plan?
    {
        print $child->getNodeValue; #should print elements
        print " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

I tried an if-statement thinking I was close but only received errors.

```
foreach $elem (@nodes)
{
    if($elem->getElementByTagName("provider")->getFirstChild->getNodeValue =~ /Vodafone/){
        print "$unit->getElementByTagName("provider")->getFirstChild->getNodeValue";
        print " || ";
        print "$unit->getElementByTagName("length")->getFirstChild->getNodeValue";
        print " || ";
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have to use XML::DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `XML::DOM` so would tend to pick up `XML::Twig` instead. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $provider = 'Vodafone';

sub print_plan_summary {
   my ( $twig, $plan ) = @_; 
   return unless $plan -> first_child_text('provider') eq $provider; 

   print join ( "||",  $plan -> first_child_text('provider'), 
                       $plan -> first_child_text('length')." months", 
                       $plan -> first_child_text('data'). " GB" );
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'plan' => \&print_plan_summary } ) -> parsefile('yourXML.xml');
```

`XML::Twig` allows you to set handlers, which take subsets of the xml (in this case `plan` elements) and process them individually. Because we can do this, we can manipulate as we go, or just 'simply' extract data from them.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use something else, it's pretty easy with [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple). Usually I don't like XML::Simple, but with this kind of straight-forward XML structure it actually works.

Just read the file (I put it in the `__DATA__` section) into a data strucutre, and then iterate over the plans. Those are in an arrayref. Now all you need to do is join the hashref values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::Simple;

my $xs   = XML::Simple->new;
my $data = $xs->XMLin( \*DATA );


foreach my $plan ( @{ $data->{internet}->{plan} } ) {
    next if $plan->{provider} ne 'Vodafone';
    say join q{ || }, $plan->{provider}, $plan->{length} . ' months', $plan->{data} . 'gb';
}
```

Comment: Personally - I'm not keen on suggesting people use XML::Simple. Even the module page suggests not doing so.

Comment: @Sobrique I know. That's why I have the disclaimer at the top.